# Unable to change the author of content using views/action

Tags: views, 8, actions

I want to change the author of multiple nodes. I have set up a new action by going to /admin/config/system/actions and then selecting "CREATE AN ADVANCED ACTION" and then "Change the author of content..."

In my view of the content type I have added the "Node operations bulk form" field.

My problem is that when I try to update any content using this method I get the error "No access to execute Change the author on the Content [TITLE]'. The user has a role giving permission to edit the content.

I have looked at the code that generates this error - it is in core/modules/system/src/Plugin/views/field/BulkForm.php

```
        // Skip execution if the user did not have access.
    if (!$action->getPlugin()->access($entity, $this->view->getUser())) {
      $this->drupalSetMessage($this->t('No access to execute %action on the @entity_type_label %entity_label.', [
        '%action' => $action->label(),
        '@entity_type_label' => $entity->getEntityType()->getLabel(),
        '%entity_label' => $entity->label()
      ]), 'error');
      continue;
    }
```

Anyone any idea what I can do to get this to work? I need to change the author of thousands of nodes, so I need to work this out.

Comment: Is that a custom plugin? There is no such action plugin in core I think. Can you share its code?

Comment: Change the author of content... is in core.

Comment: why not run a drush script ?

Answer (score 1):

I just created a module for this, which allows you to change the Author as a batch operation on /admin/content, with a custom selection step to pick the new author.

Module: [change_author_action](https://www.drupal.org/project/change_author_action)